# PDO UPDATE query deletes value(s) instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo

Can anyone see what is wrong with this script? I have verified that the data is in the $_POST array and the query-string is also formed correctly, but for some reason when this gets executed, the column(s) to be updated get emptied in the database..?

```
/* Get the ID for the house to be modified by using a hidden-field 'hiddenDescription' */
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM talot WHERE kuvaus = :description');
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST['hiddenDescription'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // The column names in the database
    $col_names = array("kaupunki", "osoite", "pintaAla", "koko", "vuosi", "hinta", "otsikko", "kuvaus", "valittaja");
    $comma = ",";
    $i = 0;
    $unprepared = 'UPDATE talot SET ';
    /* Go through the POST -array and add the column name and :$key (for binding) into the query string. Also add comma  */
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($_POST[$key])){
            // Skip hiddenDescription
            if($key != 'hiddenDescription'){
                $unprepared .= "$col_names[$i] = :$key".$comma;
            }
            // If $key was hiddenDescription decrement $i;
            else{
                $i--;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    // chop the last comma.
    $prepared = chop($unprepared, ',');
    $prepared .= ' WHERE id = :id';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($prepared);
    $i = 0;
    /* Go through the POST -array and bind values that are not empty. Again skip hiddenDescription. */
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($value)){
            if($key != 'hiddenDescription'){
                $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            else{
                $i--;
            }
        } 
        $i++;
    }
    // Bind the ID received in the first database query.
    $id = (int)$row['id'];
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if($result){
        echo 1;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: echo the sql statement and show what it returns

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(49) "UPDATE talot SET osoite = :address WHERE id = :id"
}
 : UPDATE talot SET osoite = :address WHERE id = :id

Comment: in PHP:  echo var_dump($stmt) . " : " . $prepared;

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: How? Can you give me an example of what I could post in there to make it break? I'm pretty new to all this stuff so I can't figure out anything malicious myself even though I tried a few things.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. Solved this hehe.

This:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($value)){
        if($key != 'hiddenDescription'){
            $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        else{
            $i--;
        }
    } 
    $i++;
}
```

Changed to this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => &$value){
if(!empty($value)){
    if($key != 'hiddenDescription'){
        $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    else{
        $i--;
    }
} 
$i++;
```

}

(bindParam needs &$variable):